# Install4j created windows installer

Tags: install4j

I'm evaluating install4j to create my Java app installers for Linux (rpm) and Windows (exe) platform. Towards the end of installation, I wish to modify a text file content.

Using install4j for Linux media, it allows a 'post-install' script where I can define a bash shell script to modify a text file.

However, using install4j for Windows media, there isn't any 'post-install' script where I can define a batch script.

Does anyone has the experience in using install4j for Windows media?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Run executable or batch file" action on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" tab to execute a batch file. There are also actions for modifying text files.

The post-install script for Unix archives also works for archives like DEB and RPM, there is no comparable script for Windows archives, you have to use an installer there.